# Where can I find a U-Prove implementation for WS-Trust?

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, ws-trust

I'm looking for a WCF implementation of U-Prove that was formerly on the Microsoft connect website for test and experimentation purposes.

I've seen several videos that mention U-Prove in conjunction with WCF/Cardspace, but it seems that all of those plugins have been removed and not replaced.

I would like to see those samples just to I can understand

- If the WCF binding was "upgraded" to support UProve for authentication
- If WCF was used to issue and renew a UProve token
- How and where the serialization was done (was it a custom binding or a simple service)
- Any other WCF-specific technology that may have been improved with UProve

Ultimately I want to take the "outdated" WCF examples and modernise it so a JSON token will have the same affect as what I assume the binary-based Cardspace demo used to do.

Any archived link to the outdated Microsoft Connect project, or a FOSS replacement would be a great help.

Comment: After many years of searching, an implementation is surfacing https://github.com/zeropki

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't the implementation per-se, it is a document that describes the implementation

http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=166974